# Fixed number of dashes inside path during resize

Tags: wpf, xaml, path

I have dashed path defined by `PathGeometry` like this:

```
<Path Stretch="Fill"
      StrokeDashArray="20 10"
      Stroke="Black">
      <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry Figures="M 0,0 M 0.5,0 V 1 M 1,1">
        </PathGeometry>
      </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

But when I resize the window number of dashes increase due to `StrokeDashArray` definition. 
It is possible to set fixed number of dashes during resize? For example 4 dashes or parametric length of dashes and gaps. Something like: length is equal to 1/4 of whole path?

I tried to change `ScaleTransform` for `PathGeometry` but it affect whole `path` and yes I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439153/wpf-dashed-line-fix-dashes-during-resize) question and it is different problem.

Comment: I may be reading it wrong, but it sounds like you're just looking to set StrokeDashOffset.

Comment: From my understanding of `StrokeDashOffset` it will just adjust starting position of first dash but I need to fix number of dashes during resize. I will update question to be more clear.

Comment: So you want it to remain the same amount of dashes, but let them grow in size with resize? Yea sorry, must not be visualizing what you're asking correctly.

Comment: Yea that is my goal.

Comment: If that's the case, as far as I know you're going to have to have to fake it. Be it by say putting a bunch of thin width Rectangles in a StackPanel or something, or a bunch of individual lines in a compound path etc.